# Django hosting on Windows server

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, django, wsgi

I'm running in a "Windows only" environment. We have a few linux boxes but we're not allowed to use Linux in our DMZ (something about it being less secure. ha.)

We're currently developing a couple of django apps as for a potential switch from Java running on Tomcat.

Since I have no choice in what server OS to use, what is the recommendation about what to use on Windows?

I've seen a lot of reference here to WSGI on Apache. I've heard of others running NGINX for the static files and FCGI for the django apps. What is the least complicated of the setup possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article - [Running Django on Windows (with performance tests)](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/)